# WordPress NextGEN Gallery watermark feature not working

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have been trying for a couple of hours to get the NextGEN Gallery watermark feature to work with no success. The text watermark will work but the image watermark won't.

I have done a lot of reading on Google, and mainly what's coming up is that I need to

- use an absolute URL to the watermark;
- have `allow_url_fopen= On` in `php.ini`; and
- apply the watermark to the images

all of which I have done, and still no luck.

Has anyone come across the same issue and solved it? If so, how? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Below are the server settings if it helps...



    Operating System : Linux (64 Bit)
    Server : Apache/2
    Memory usage : 26.51 MByte
    MYSQL Version : 5.5.25a-log
    SQL Mode : Not set
    PHP Version : 5.3.10
    PHP Safe Mode : Off
    PHP Allow URL fopen : On
    PHP Memory Limit : 128
    PHP Max Upload Size : 64M
    PHP Max Post Size : 64M
    PCRE Backtracking Limit : 500000
    PHP Max Script Execute Time : 30s
    PHP Exif support : Yes ( V1.4 )
    PHP IPTC support : Yes
    PHP XML support : Yes

Comment: Graphic Library

    GD Version : bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
    FreeType Support : Yes
    FreeType Linkage : with freetype
    T1Lib Support : No
    GIF Read Support : Yes
    GIF Create Support : Yes
    JPEG Support : Yes
    PNG Support : Yes
    WBMP Support : Yes
    XPM Support : Yes
    XBM Support : Yes
    JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support : No

Comment: I am getting positive results applying a watermark only with PNG images. JPG and GIF images are not working in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking tirelessly for a resolution I decided to host the image on a different server, the watermark worked straight away! The server in question is heart internet so I will be getting in contact with them and asking why its not working!

If anyone else comes across this issue try and host the image on a different server, that kind of solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing font and size worked for me.